# How many times do I have to perform event x (with a probability of y) to ensure that it happens z times with a confidence of 95%?

Tags: probability

Preferably in a formula please.

E.X. How many times do you have to roll a dice to have a 95% chance rolling a total of five sixes?

Comment: Is it also allowed to roll more than five sixes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. Rolling a cubic dice $n$ times, $X$ being the number of successes, leads to a  binomial distribution:
$$
X \sim B(n,1/6).
$$ You are looking for the smallest integer $n$ such that
$$
P(X=5)\geq 0.95
$$ that is for the smallest integer $n$ such that

> $$
> \binom{\color{blue}{n}}{5}\times (1/6)^5\times (5/6)^{\color{blue}{n}-5}\geq 0.95 \tag1
> $$

You may simplify $(1)$ and then find an integer solution with a numerical method.

You may extend the preceding path for a genral case.

Comment: Thanks. How would you write this as a numerical formula?

Comment: How would you put variables into the formula where x is the probability of an individual event and y is the number of times an occurrence is needed?

Comment: One may look for the smallest integer $\color{blue}{n}$ such that $$ \binom{\color{blue}{n}}{y}\times p^y\times (1-p)^{\color{blue}{n}-y}\geq 0.95.$$

Comment: So I could just keep running this function with the values for n increasing by 1 each time, and when the result is >= 0.95, I have my answer? Can you provide sample solutions I can test against to make sure I'm implementing this correctly? Thanks in advance, Zach.

Comment: Is it $y$ successes *exactly* or *at least* $y$ successes? The former case doesn't always admit a solution, the latter case may be solved with Wolframalpha.